# piping string input into python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to make a simple application `hello.py` in python that prints the piped string, so that when I call

```bash
echo "Hello StackOverflow" | python3 hello.py
```

The python app prints

```
Hello StackOverflow
```

What do I write in my `hello.py` file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import sys

for line in sys.stdin:
    sys.stdout.write(line)
```

Input:

```
echo "Hello StackOverflow" | python3 hello.py
```

Output:

```
Hello StackOverflow
```

Comment: Yep, tried it out, it works!